# core/gallery get figcaption text

Tags: media, gallery

I try to get gutenberg media gallery block output, and want to use default figcaption text feature for images titles (for js lightbox).
How can i get this property figcaption text value?

```
add_filter( 'render_block', function( $block_content, $block ) {
    if ( 'core/gallery' !== $block['blockName'] || ! isset( $block['attrs']['ids'] ) ) {
           return $block_content;
    }
        $li = '';

    foreach( (array) $block['attrs']['ids'] as $id ) {
        $li .= sprintf( '<li><a href="%s" data-lightbox="photo" data-title="%s"><img src="%s" class="w-100"></a></li>',
        wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, '' )[0],
        'FIGCAPTION TEXT',
        wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'thumbnail' )[0] );

    }
    return sprintf( '<ul id="gallery-grid">%s</ul>', $li ); 
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re right...the figcaptions are encoded as html in `$block['innerHTML']`. You could do sth. like `$tmpArray = explode('</li>',$block['innerHTML']);` before your `foreach` loop to split the HTML string into an array that matches your gallery items and inside the loop `strip_tags($tmpArray[i]);` to strip away all html tags and only get the text string inside `<figcaption></figcaption>`. You’ll only need to add a counter `i` to your loop to have an index for the `$tmpArray`.

Comment: Thank for idea! Seems to no direct methods to get this value by property, only html parse.

Answer (score 0):

Try `wp_get_attachment_caption( $id )` for caption and `get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true )` for alt-text

Comment: Thank for your reply! Unfortunately this return internal image properties, not from media gallery gutenberg block.